# Illustrator ExtendScript save() Method

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, jsx, extendscript

Does the save method in Illustrator offer a callback function which executes when the save is done?

Answer (score 0):

No. It doesn't. For my Extendscript always felt like it was synchronous. Maybe you try something like this:

```
var doc = app.documents.add();
doc.saveAs(File('~/Desktop/testfile.ai'));
if(doc.saved === true){
    $.writeln('yeah');
}else{
    $.writeln('buhu.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible if you are using only Extendedscript but with the latest version of Illustrator CC and integration with CEP, we can use events and can write code js(java script) that will execute whenever save operation is done in Illustrator.